# Android horizontal scroll in grid view

Tags: android, android-gridview, horizontalscrollview, android-gridlayout

I want to implement a horizontal grid view where images and all other descriptions will be provided by a server.

I am able to put images inside a grid view but it is scrolling vertically even if I put my grid view inside a HorizontalScrollView.

It should look like: left image, center image, right image. If there is any previous or next image then that image should remain partially visible at the left and right edges of the screen. On scrolling left or right, the next/previous image should move to the center.

Can any one tell me how best to implement this behavior without using a third party library?

Comment: Welcome to SO! What have you investigated and tried so far?

Comment: thxx stkent for ur prompt response.
i tried to put my gridview inside the HorizontalScrollView. but images are coming vertically , i want it horizontally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suggestion would be to swap out the GridView for a RecyclerView. The RecyclerView + LayoutManager combination allows much more variety in layouts of this type. From [the RecyclerView.LayoutManager documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.LayoutManager.html):

> By changing the LayoutManager a RecyclerView can be used to implement a standard vertically scrolling list, a uniform grid, staggered grids, horizontally scrolling collections and more.

You would want to look at the [`GridLayoutManager`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/GridLayoutManager.html) to start with. My guess is that the orientation parameter in the constructor:

`GridLayoutManager(Context context, int spanCount, int orientation, boolean reverseLayout)`

may allow you to set up horizontal scrolling quite easily. At worst, you may have to do some custom touch handling to manage horizontal motion.

Comment: i was trying to achieve it by putting gridview inside horizontalscrollview ?

<HorizontalScrollView .... 

        <GridView....
          ...........
        </GridView>

</HorizontalScrollView>

is this incorrect way ?

Comment: I don't think that will work - the GridView, as a child of the HorizontalScrollView, will likely be consuming all touch events. As a result, the HorizontalScrollView will never be triggered and all scrolling will still be vertical. You could extend the HorizontalScrollView and try to intercept touch events when appropriate, but that is a lot of work. On the other hand, the RecyclerView+LayoutManager were designed especially for their flexibility in situations like yours!

Comment: ok thanks stkent , let me explore and try some RecyclerView Widget Example.so that i can get some basic idea as i never used this before.

Comment: hey stkent , thanks alot for ur help . i am able to achive horizontal scroll list by using RecyclerView . i got a very usefull link http://hmkcode.com/android-simple-recyclerview-widget-example/ and i created my constructor 'recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager (this, 1, 0, false));'   

this made my image list horizontal scroll . now i have to check for central lock.

thanks a lot for ur helo.u made my day :-)