# how to display Gridview items in HorizontalScrollView

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I am trying to display the gridview with 3 columns in HorizontalScrollView and my layout is like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="1dp"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <HorizontalScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scrollbars="none"
        android:id="@+id/title_horizontalScrollView"
        android:layout_margin="1dp"
        android:fillViewport="false">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">
            <GridView
                android:id="@+id/videoGridView"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:stretchMode="columnWidth" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </HorizontalScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

while i am adding items to gridview adapter it is showing empty space without items.Please help me how to display HorizontalScrollView with gridview items.
My GridView adapter is like

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/line"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageview"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:src="@drawable/play" />
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="2dp"
                android:orientation="vertical">
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/Title"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageview"/>
             </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>

var tvTitle = view.FindViewById(Resource.Id.Title) as TextView;
var tvImage = view.FindViewById(Resource.Id.imageview) as ImageView;
tvTitle.SetText(item.Title, TextView.BufferType.Normal);
```

Comment: I'm not sure that this will work, take a look here for something similar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27469347/android-horizontal-scroll-in-grid-view

Comment: Can you show the gridview adapter code?

Comment: you should use recyclerview with horizontal orientation

Answer (score 1):

The best way use recycleview and set its layout horizontal like

```
LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = ...
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

//when you want horizontal
layoutManager.setOrientation(context,LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL,false);
```

For example visit below url

http://blog.nkdroidsolutions.com/android-horizontal-vertical-recyclerview-example/

And if you want to know more about recycleview visit below url.

http://blog.nkdroidsolutions.com/android-horizontal-vertical-recyclerview-example/